# How do I find the kernel for this map?

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis

$G_1 = \mathbb{Q}$, $G_2=\{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| \, \text{is finite}\}$ and $f: G_1 \to G_2$ defined as $f(r)=e^{-2 \pi i r}$.

The kernel of $f$ is supposed to be $\mathbb{Z}$, and I'm not sure how to get that.

Comment: I assume $\lvert z \rvert$ here means the *multiplicative order* of $z$, and not its distance from $0$?

Comment: @pjs36, No, $|z| = |a + ib| = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$.

Comment: Then $G_2 = \Bbb C$.

Comment: @IvoTerek Does that mean $f$ can't be surjective? Because I'm also supposed to show that.

Comment: Precisely, because the exponential is never zero. Are you really sure that $|z|$ is the length?

Comment: @IvoTerek That's not mentioned in the problem. I've written it here exactly as it appears in one of the past papers. I'm assuming $|z|$ refers to the length. What happens if we consider it to be the order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet if you understand properly what $G_2$ is, you'll have no problem.

$G_2$ is almost certainly supposed to be the set of all complex numbers with finite multiplicative order -- the statements you're asked to prove are simply not true if $G_2$ is anything else.

Since $\Bbb C$ naturally has two operations, it's *also* important to understand what operation we're performing in $G_2$ as well: and it *must* be multiplication (if it were addition, we'd be solving $f(r) = e^{-2i\pi r} = 0$, which has no solutions). Thus, to find the kernel, you're solving $f(r) = 1$, the multiplicative identity of $\Bbb C$ (and hence $G_2 \leq \Bbb C$).

Now, since $f(r) = e^{-2i \pi r} = \cos(-2\pi r) + i \sin (-2\pi r)$, the first result doesn't take long.